# how many circles can pass through three points? (demonstration)

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, circles, triangles

How can I prove that just one circle passes through three points?. I, at some way, asked it in a forum, but no one answered me, so I thought could make a forum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the system of equations has only one solution? Coordinate geometry.

Comment: You can have one circle passing through 3 **distinct non-collinear** points. You can have have more than one circle passing through 3 non-distinct points and you can't have any circles pass through 3 distinct collinear points.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have point $A,B,C$. Consider the fact that the center of the circle $O$ has the same distance from $A,B,C$, then it has to lie on the vertical bisector of both $AB$ and $BC$. Assuming $A,B,C$ not on a same line, there 's only one $O$ possible.

Comment: But, couldn´t there be a point $O$ that has the same distance to $A,B$ and $C$ and isn´t the centre of the circumference?

Comment: There is only one point that has the same distance to $A,B,C$. And by definition it is the center of the circle which you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Delta ABC$ our triangle.

If $O$ is a center of the circle then $OA=OB=OC$, which says that $O$ placed on midperpendiculars to $AB$, to $AC$ and to $BC$, which are unique.

Comment: What is the term for using an adjective as a verb, as you have done here with "unique"? Good answer though, +1 :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, great question

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee My English is very bad. You can fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Apparently, [using another part of speech as a verb is called "verbification" or "verbing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)#Verbification)
 ... I had heard of the term "verbing" but I thought it only applied to using nouns as verbs, but in actuality it applies to using anything (that is not normally a verb) as a verb.

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee I fixed. See now please.

Comment: Your answer is great! It was great before as well, I was just being silly :)

Comment: @Zubin are you a native English speaker? I think you are Bengalee? May be প্রবাসী বাঙ্গালী !!!

Answer (score 1):

As mtheorylord commented, let us write the equations
$$(x_1-a)^2+(y_1-b)^2=r^2 \tag 1$$ $$(x_2-a)^2+(y_2-b)^2=r^2 \tag 2$$ $$(x_3-a)^2+(y_3-b)^2=r^2 \tag 3$$
Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ and $(1)$ from $(3)$; this gives two linear equations in $a,b$.
$$2(x_1-x_2) a+2(y_1-y_2)b=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2) \tag 4$$
$$2(x_1-x_3) a+2(y_1-y_3)b=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2) \tag 5$$ If the solution does exist (I let you finding the conditions - it is easy), it is unique.

Solve $(4)$ and $(5)$ for $a$ and $b$ and replace in $(1)$ to get $r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The general equation of a circle is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ where $a,b$ refers to it's centre and $r$ is its radius.

Suppose more than one circle pass through three given points. Then, the equation

$(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2=(x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2$ , must have $3$ solutions which is impossible.

hence, only one circle can pass through three points